# Amazon S3 retorna "Service Unavailable" al subir archivos desde laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, aws, amazon-s3

Al intentar subir un video de 55 minutos de duración con un peso de 86.6MB, desde laravel utilizando

```
 $video = $request->file("video");
 $path = Storage::disk('s3')->put("videos", $video);
 $path = Storage::disk('s3')->url($path);

 return response()->json(["msg" => "Video subido exitosamente!","path"=>$path]);
```

Despues de un cierto tiempo me retorna "Service Unavailable"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He modificado mi php.ini subiendo el tiempo de max execution time y demas, pero no ha tenido solución ya que el error proviene de S3, intente subirlos mediante stream y no hubo cambio alguno.

Igualmente he intentado con videos de menos duración y los sube sin problemas.
¿¿Alguna solución??

Comment: Hola Fernando! Es seguro que el problema es por S3? No me suena que haya limitación con archivos que se manden a S3.  Usas nginx? Apache? Otro?

Comment: Hola @msalinas es lo que supongo, me puse en contacto con soporte de mi proveedor de web hosting y dice que eso ya no depende de ellos. 
Aparte me da mas pensar que es por S3 ya que si guardo el video en mi web , sin subirlo a S3 lo sube igual sin problemas.

Comment: he leído algo por ahí, pero no he leído nadie que cuente una solución. De todas maneras, por si te puede servir como "parche", yo en algún proyecto tengo el bucket de S3 como link simbólico en una carpeta de.mi servidor. Para conseguir esto uso [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse). Por si te puede servir como alternativa a lo que buscas